# Google Sheets - Script Slow - Dependent Dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have three dropdown boxes that are dependent on each other. The code works fine but is really slow, 3 seconds to update the next box. I'm used to VBA and this is no problem in Excel, but it's really show in Google Sheets. I added a `Browser.msgBox("here");` to the first line of the code and from changing the dropdown it takes 2 seconds to display it. This can't be normal?

Here's the code: (The list options are stored in Named Ranges, the correct name is generated and stored in the optName below )

```
function onEdit(event) {


  if (!event) return;

  //SETTINGS

  var ss = event.source;
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName()

  if(sheet.getName() == 'Damages & Repairs July 2018') {
    var lcol = 3; // leftmost column number you are monitoring
    var rcol =6; // rightmost column number you are monitoring
  }else{
    var lcol = 4; // leftmost column number you are monitoring
    var rcol =7; // rightmost column number you are monitorin
  }
  //


  if (sheetName == 'Refunds July 2018' || sheetName == 'Exchanges July 2018'|| sheetName == 'Damages & Repairs July 2018') {

    var sourceCol = r.getColumn();
    var sourceRow = r.getRow();

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

     if(sheetName == 'Damages & Repairs July 2018') {

       if(sourceCol == 4) {
         var optName = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, lcol ).getValue() + sheet.getRange(sourceRow, lcol + 1).getValue();
       } else if ( sourceCol == 5) {
         var optName = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, lcol + 1).getValue();
       } else {
         var optName = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol).getValue();
       }
     } else {
       if(sourceCol == 5) {
         var optName = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, lcol ).getValue() + sheet.getRange(sourceRow, lcol + 1).getValue();
       } else if ( sourceCol == 6) {
         var optName = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, lcol + 1).getValue();
       } else {
         var optName = sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol).getValue();
       }
     }

    var optName = optName.replace(/\s/g, "");

    var tableRange = ss.getRangeByName(optName).getValues();
    var optList = "";

    if (sourceCol >= lcol && sourceCol <= rcol) {

   // define the dropdown/validation rules
   var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(tableRange);

   // Clear the validation
   //sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1).clearDataValidations()
   //sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1).clearContent()
   // set the dropdown validation for the row
   sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1).setDataValidation(rangeRule); // set range to your range

    }

  } 
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

**UPDATE**

I changed the code to this - but still not that much faster:

```
function onEdit(event) {


  //SETTINGS

  var ss = event.source;
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var sourceCol = r.getColumn();
  var sourceRow = r.getRow();


  if(sheet.getName() == 'Damages & Repairs July 2018') {
    var lcol = 3; // leftmost column number you are monitoring
    var rcol =6; // rightmost column number you are monitoring
  }else{
    var lcol = 4; // leftmost column number you are monitoring
    var rcol =7; // rightmost column number you are monitorin
  }

  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('R' + sourceRow + 'C' + lcol + ':R' + sourceRow + 'C' + rcol).getValues();

  if (sheetName == 'Refunds July 2018' || sheetName == 'Exchanges July 2018'|| sheetName == 'Damages & Repairs July 2018') {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

     if(sheetName == 'Damages & Repairs July 2018') {

       if(sourceCol == 4) {
         var optName = sourceRange[0][0] + sourceRange[0][1];
       } else if ( sourceCol == 5) {
         var optName = sourceRange[0][1];
       } else {
         var optName =sourceRange[0][0];
       }

     } else {

       if(sourceCol == 5) {
         var optName = sourceRange[0][0] + sourceRange[0][1];
       } else if ( sourceCol == 6) {
         var optName = sourceRange[0][1];
       } else {
         var optName = sourceRange[0][0];
       }

     }


    var optName = optName.replace(/\s/g, "");

    var tableRange = ss.getRangeByName(optName).getValues();
    var optList = "";

    if (sourceCol >= lcol && sourceCol <= rcol) {

   // define the dropdown/validation rules
   var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(tableRange);

   // Clear the validation
   sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1).clearDataValidations()
   sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1).clearContent()
   // set the dropdown validation for the row
   sheet.getRange(sourceRow, sourceCol + 1).setDataValidation(rangeRule); // set range to your range

    }

  } 
}
```

Comment: Excel runs on your machine... Google Sheets is on Google servers.. network io is real

Comment: Thanks, please see my update above